# Iterate through submitted sqlform fields and values in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

Here is my code:

```
def index():

    form = SQLFORM(db.sometable)

    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash = 'your data is posted'
```

In above code, I just want that when the form is submitted, I should be able to iterate through its fields(inputs) and corresponding values.
So how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the `form` has been accepted, `form.vars` is a Storage object (basically a `dict`) of the fields' values.

Comment: Is it true with SQLFORM as well in my case? I get an empty object in `form.vars` after submit as here http://imgur.com/a/E6e3V

Comment: That's how it should work; can't say much about your case, given how little you have shown about it.

Comment: ok I noted that once the form has been "accepted". It works now after form is successfully accepted!